# Can you turn Elasticsearch Profile API output into a flame graph?

Tags: elasticsearch, flamegraph

We've been using [Flame Graph](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2927301) recently for CPU profiling.  Is there a converter for turning [Elasticsearch Profile API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-profile.html) output into a Flame Graph (or will I need to write one?)  I looked at [Brendan Gregg's Flame Graph project](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph), but I didn't see any examples for Elasticsearch Profile API output.  I think that the Elasticsearch nested profiler output would roll up nicely into a Flame Graph, but it's also possible I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [ongoing effort](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/16423) that started 4 years ago but it's not yet available in Kibana.
Elastic charts [supports it](https://github.com/elastic/elastic-charts/pull/965) as well as you can see [in the gallery](https://elastic.github.io/elastic-charts/?path=/story/flame-alpha--flame-chart&globals=theme:light;background:white).

Until it's officially supported, since Kibana [supports Vega](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/8.3/vega.html) (which doesn't support flame graphs yet), someone brought up the question and [got a raw answer](https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/1736) on how to proceed. Not sure if that cuts it, but worth a try.